# Send file based dummy data from Angularjs REST resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am trying to let UI development proceed without needing to be coupled to a backend.  My the normal REST api is being built like:

```
a.factory('Sample', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource(baseUrl() + '/sample/:id', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{id:''}, isArray:true, cache:false},
      update: { method:'PUT' },
      remove: { method:'DELETE'}
  });
}]);
```

This is fine when there is an actual backend.  However, for development purposes (NOT Testing), canned data from a file is desired.  This can be achieved like:

```
['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/sampleList.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.sampleData = data;
  });
}]
```

Obviously, I'm no expert here, but I am wondering if there is an easy way to combine these two approaches such that the $resource REST instance can return (for GET requests anyway), canned data from a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why didn't you say this was such a newb question or that you never RTFM?  Oh wait, this is my own question!  So, sorry folks, didn't realize this was quite so trivial - there is a 'URL' parameter available on every such method.  While this will only work for Mockups or UI dev before the backend is done, for the above, all I needed to do was:

```
a.factory('Sample', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource(baseUrl() + '/sample/:id', {}, {
      query: {url: 'data/sampleList.json', method:'GET', params:{id:''}, isArray:true, cache:false},
      update: { method:'PUT' },
      remove: { method:'DELETE'}
    });
}]);
```

qed